# using external API in php: Links are incorrect

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to using and API in php.
I have an existing call to an external API, which works and looks like this:

```
// $id = "227";
// $url = "external-api.com/places/$id?;
// url above works, too
$url = "external-api.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$partner_code:$secret_code");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  
echo($result);
```

On my local server the page is displayed correctly when I enter http://localhost/mytest/mytest.php

The page also displays links and when I click on of them, it shows me the page could not be found. This is because the target is `localhost/places/227` and there is no such page.

What I want now is that a call to `localhost/places/227` shows a result of an API call to `external-api.com/places/227`. Just like in the example above, except that this time `$url` has changed to `external-api.com/places/227`.

**But** this shouldn't happen to every link on my website. Just to those links that were retrieved by the API call.

So I think this is what I want: When the link to `/places/227` is clicked I want the above php script to be executed again except that the varaible for `$url` has changed to `$url = "external-api.com/places/227;`

Comment: Are you change base_url in config.php???

Comment: so, you want that the person which access this to go on API's website?

Comment: can't you do a search and replace?

Comment: @Edwin no I want all links working just like in $host. So if the link originally goes to /places/227 I want to use this adress calling API and showing the result.

Comment: @Akintunde you mean I should just modify $result?

Comment: it's not clear what you want, because in the comments you say that at `/places/227` it shows you the result..and what links? I think you may need to use `routing`, maybe something like this: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html#routing

Comment: @Edwin maybe, I don't know. I will try to improve the question to make it more clear

Comment: I think you will need to implement a routing system to get your id=227 and then through your controller to send the curl request to this api. Then the result you can show in your view. For implementing this architecture you have a lot of frameworks to help you. You can start with the one I've mentioned before or chose another one.

Comment: @Edwin I thought it must be something very obvious and easy. At the and I only want to load the same php page with one line changed, right?

Comment: Side note: the `CURLOPT_URL` option expects a URL, not a host. It works because it assumes HTTP but it may get confusing if API changes to HTTPS some day. (Though it's confusing so far, because the host includes`/places/$id?`.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I changed the naming of the variable now

Comment: @Sadik you can hack it everytime, but I think is better to have a good architecture behind your code. I'm not that fit with the .htaccess, but I think you can rewrite some paths to do your work. Though I wouldn't recommend this solution.